Weak* convergence in trace class
Given $A_n \overset{*}{\rightharpoonup} A$ in trace class and $\mathrm{Trace}\left|A_n\right| = 1$. I want to prove/disprove that $\mathrm{Trace}\left|A_n - A\right| + \mathrm{Trace}\left|A\right| \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$. When the trace-class is replaced by Hilbert-Schmidt operators and $\mathrm{Trace}\left|\cdot\right|$ is replace by $\mathrm{Trace}\left|\cdot\right|^2$, I can prove the above claim using the Hilbert structure of Hilbert-Schmidt space. However, I meet difficulties in the case of trace class.
Thank you very much for your help.

No, this is not true. Let $H = \ell^2$. For each $n \geq 2$, let $v_n \in H$ be,
$$v_n = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n}}e_0 + \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{n^2}}(e_1 + \cdots + e_n)$$
One may verify that $v_n$ are all unit vectors and $v_n \rightharpoonup \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}e_0$ weakly. Thus, $A_n = |v_n\rangle\langle e_0|$ satisfies $\text{Tr}(|A_n|) = 1$ and $A_n \overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup} A := \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}|e_0\rangle\langle e_0|$ weak$^\ast$ in trace class operators. However, we have,
$$\|v_n - \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}e_0\|^2 = (\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n}} - \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}})^2 + n \cdot (\frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{n^2}) \to \frac{1}{2}$$
as $n \to \infty$. Thus,
$$\begin{split}
\text{Tr}(|A_n - A|) + \text{Tr}(|A|) &= \text{Tr}(\Large|\normalsize|v_n - \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}e_0\rangle\langle e_0|\Large|\normalsize) + \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\\
&= \|v_n - \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}e_0\| + \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\\
&\to \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} \neq 1
\end{split}$$

Thank you very much for your nice counter example! A small typo in your proof, it should be $A_n \overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup} A$.

@LarryBaynes You’re right. Fixed.
